# import opencv without using "sudo" on Jetson Nano Terminal

Tags: python, opencv, sudo, nvidia-jetson-nano

I have been using `OpenCV` for a long time on `Jetson Nano`. I always started my codes on `Jetson Nano` terminal with `sudo` command.

For example:

```
sudo python3 process.py
```

When I do:

```
python3 process.py
```

...I can not import opencv. How can I import `opencv` without using `sudo command on terminal?

Could you please help me?

Comment: How did you install opencv? In a virtual environment?

Comment: Yunus' questions is great. Additionally, does the script need to anything `sudo` related ? (e.g. GPIO pins/etc.) ? (Might not, but always worth double checking :) )

Comment: I installed the OpenCV from this link: github.com/JetsonHacksNano/buildOpenCV. I don't know if it uses virtual environment or not.
I use only cv2.imshow command in the script to test my camera.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check sys.path
Run python with no sudo:

```
python3
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.path)
```

Then compare output with python which run with sudo:

```
sudo python3
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.path)
```

I think your outputs will be different. Need to make them the same.

Comment: The result of python3

            import sys print(sys.path)

'/home/mucahid/c4aarch64_installer/lib/python37.zip', '/home/mucahid/c4aarch64_installer/lib/python3.7', '/home/mucahid/c4aarch64_installer/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/home/mucahid/c4aarch64_installer/lib/python3.7/site-packages'

Comment: The result of sudo python3

            import sys print(sys.path)

'/usr/lib/python36.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.6', '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/home/mucahid/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/Jetson.GPIO-2.0.8-py3.6.egg', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3.6/dist-packages']

I am not used to Linux system still, so I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Are you by any chance using conda environment?

If so, the python packages installed (system-wide) by the OpenCV build script won't be available in your virtual environment. To solve this, create a symbolic link from your system python site-packages to conda environment site-packages.

Usually it will be like this, (for cv2 specifically) -

```
ln -s /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/python3.6/cv2.cpython-36m-aarch64-linux-gnu.so /home/mucahid/c4aarch64_installer/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cv2.so
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I solved the problem.

When you install Python API for ZED Camera there is a step:
To install it run :
python3 -m pip install pyzed-3.1-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl

I changed it as

sudo python3 -m pip install pyzed-3.1-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl

and it worked. Now I can get images from python script by sudo python3 process.py command on the terminal.